# generate merchant reference in payfort payment gateway

Tags: android, payfort

I am integrating payfort payment gateway in my android application. I have generate token using rest api 
     https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi and now I have to pass that token to fort sdk for the transaction.

But Merchant reference also needs to generated to pass into the fort sdk. I can't find anything on how to generate merchant reference as anything not given in the payfort documentation.

I have also talk to the support , they said we have to create merchant reference by our own alogrithm

Can anybody know how to create merchant reference ?? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
String device_id = FortSdk.getDeviceId(this);
    Log.e("device_iddd",device_id+"");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("command", "AUTHORIZATION");
    map.put("amount",String.valueOf(1));
    map.put("language", "en");
    map.put("merchant_reference", "r1FANA78-ok00tH0");
    map.put("currency","SAR");
    map.put("customer_name", "bharat");
    map.put("customer_email", "bharat56@gmai.com");
    map.put("order_description", "Description");
    map.put("return_url", "http://faza.fazadigital.com/Faza_WS/payfortReturnPage.php");
    map.put("sdk_token", "441E41CFFF2E49F2E053321E320A4884");

    fortRequest.setRequestMap(map);
    try {
        FortSdk.getInstance().registerCallback(this, fortRequest, FortSdk.ENVIRONMENT.TEST, 10, fortCallback, new FortInterfaces.OnTnxProcessed() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(Map<String, String> requestParamsMap, Map<String, String> responseMap) {
                showProgress(false);
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : responseMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    Log.e("cancel", key + "////////" + value);
                    // do stuff
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, String> requestParamsMap, Map<String, String> fortResponseMap) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fortResponseMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    Log.e("responsee", key + "////////" + value);
                    // do stuff
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Map<String, String> requestParamsMap, Map<String, String> fortResponseMap) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fortResponseMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    Log.e("failure", key + "////////" + value);
                    // do stuff
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code for what you had done till now?

Comment: I am using previous merchant reference here ...which i have got from somewhere but it gives an error "Duplicate order number"

Comment: Did you checked this one https://testfort.payfort.com/api/ ?

Comment: yes..i am following that api..But there is not section about this

Comment: Actually merchant reference and access code are fixed that are generated for the registered user on payfort. This is not an issue with merchant reference.

Comment: merchant_identifier and access code are fixed but we have to generate unique merchant reference each time for the particular transaction

Comment: "The merchant_reference algorithm should be implemented from your side not from our side so we can received a new and unique merchant_reference for each time" . this is the answer from support team

Comment: Yes, In my code for purchage command I am passing murchant reference as system current time in milli seconds String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: I have sample for payfort will share but need time.

Comment: Ok..i think thats what i am looking for

Comment: Yeah..that would be great help as i am stuck in this for a very long time

Comment: I get the error message "Token name does not exist" when i pass current time in merchant reference

Comment: You can mail me the sample at tesapp1995@gmail.com whenever you will have time.Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure, tomorrow I will share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your code you are using merchant_reference as a static value but merchant_refernce should not be static it should be a unique value every time as system current time in milliseconds String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

Your merchant identifier and access code value should be same always which are generated at the time of registration at the PayFort. These are on the basis of merchant registration and unique for every registered user.

Comment: Yeah..I am using current time in merchant reference and it works ..Thanks

Comment: Yeah, already shared link in answer is my sample. Need to do some documentation. If you download and run this it works like a charm.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid hi, How can generate merchant_identifier? of where I can find this value?

Comment: When you create your project account at payfort then you will get merchant identifier and access code.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid thanks for reply. is those keys got on email? if I loss email then is there any why to get those keys back?

Comment: I never do this kind of stuff, i think you can get it from same project info

Comment: @ReadyAndroid you received those key after registration right? I mean on email after creating account.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid are those key showing after login ? can you please share url where those key showing?